# load balancing in django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django server which responds to a call like this `127.0.0.1:8000/ao/`. Before adding further applications to the server, I would like to experiment the load balancing which are supported by Django.

Can anyone please explain how to implement load balancing. I spent sometime in understanding the architecture but was unable to find a solution.

I work on Windows OS and I am new to servers.

Comment: This is not a programming topic and it is too broad as well.

Comment: Can u provide some insights over this topic. @KlausD.

Comment: @Venkat Take a look at [this series of posts](http://rahmonov.me/posts/run-a-django-app-with-gunicorn-in-ubuntu-16-04/). Let me know if you have questions regarding posts.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Thanks for the guidance. I have some questions for you.

1. My server will have only RESTful APIs. So why will I still need Nginx to be run? AM not convinced with the research I made for this.

2. I followed your tutorial, but couldn't quite follow it. In Part - II when I start my Nginx server and try to access, it says add `0.0.0.0 to ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

3. I made a simple test with 3 workers of Gunicorn, It was not able to handle 500 requests at a time.How should I be testing and do you suggest any testing procedures?

Am sorry that this is quite long.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Load balancing is not anything to do with Django. It is something you implement at a much higher layer, via servers that sit in front of the machines that Django is running on.

However, if you've just started creating your site, it is much too early to start thinking about this.